# PHP: Right way to put string in function argument

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Working on some AJAX functionality and have stuck with the basic problem. Can't find the right answer.

I want to send a string in argument. My code looks like this.

```
echo '<li class="dropdown-item" onclick="term_ajax_get('. $s->term_id .', '. $s->name .')">';
```

In Chrome it's rendering:

```
<li class="dropdown-item" onclick="term_ajax_get(797, Cats)">Cats</li>
```

But when i click to element, i get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

My jQ function just in case

```
function term_ajax_get(termID, termName) {
    jQuery("a.ajax").removeClass("current");
    jQuery("a.ajax").addClass("current"); 
    jQuery("#loading-animation").show();
    var ajaxurl = 'http://localhost:3333/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {"action": "game-filter", term: termID, name: termName },
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery(".games__cnt").html(response);
            jQuery("#loading-animation").hide();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine with term_id, but not quite the same result from string. I tried back-slashes and every solution that i could find in web. But still can't get it.

Comment: The problem is with escaping your quotes, per the answer by @NathanEdwards. However, you should really avoid having `onclick` events embedded in your HTML like that at all; it's considered bad practice. You should use jQuery to define the events separate from your HTML code. Use `$('.dropdown-item').click()` or something similar for this. If you do it right, you can avoid having to generate any JavaScript code at all in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add escaped quotes around the string parameter.

```
echo '<li class="dropdown-item" onclick="term_ajax_get('. $s->term_id .', \''. $s->name .'\')">';
```

Which should print out like

```
<li class="dropdown-item" onclick="term_ajax_get(797, 'Cats')">Cats</li>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried escaped quotes several times, but with wrong syntax. I fill shame.

Comment: @NickAdamov, it happens to the best of us! Especially with PHP/JS

Answer (score -1):

```
termName
```

variable in your function expect a parameter to be a string, try adding `'$s->name'` to make it a string value.